# VB.NET Multiple Replace In Text File

Tags: vb.net

I have 2 files , one index.html which is more like a template , and output index file which is a new file. the first index file contains ##1 , ##2 .... ##24 inside it , and i want those to be replaced with some links i provide within a text file.

Let me explain my code. First i create my output file. 
i declare the line array containing links which will replace the ##1 .... ##24.
i loop 24 times to replace all ## with the Links provided from allLines. In the final file it only replaces some of the ## and not all

My form looks like this https://s32.postimg.org/6h3ug8s7p/Untitled.png

The problem is that it doesnt replace all links , it replaces only some of them and this is really weird.

```
    IO.File.Create(TextBox3.Text).Dispose()

    Dim allLines As String() = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(TextBox1.Text)
    For c As Integer = 1 To 24 Step 1

        My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(TextBox3.Text, My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(TextBox2.Text).Replace("##" & c, allLines(c - 1)), True)

    Next
```

Comment: Does it have any kind of exact issue about the items not replaced? Does it for example always not replace the first file/last file etc? Or is it completely random? Also can you check using a break point if the array contains all items correctly?

Comment: It is not completely random ... it replaces the first , then the 10th 11th .... 20th. i will test the array furthermore

Comment: Rather than continually reading and writing the file within the loop, you should read all the text in into a string first, do all your replacements and then write it out once. You keep overwriting the file noted by `TextBox3.Text` with a *single* replacement from TextBox2 file. My guess is you are only seeing the "final" replacement(s). `Dim sb as new StringBuilder(File.ReadAllText(TextBox3.Text)) / For i = 1 to 24 / sb.Replace("##"&c, allLines(c-1)) / Next i`  Then finally, `File.WriteAllText(TextBox3.Text, sb.ToString())`

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for , i did some minor modifications to mach my project and it now works perfectly, Thanks @pinkfloydx33 you saved me a lot of time.

Comment: I've added it as an official answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are continuously reading/writing the file using the *same source* file (TextBox2.Text). `File.WriteAllText` overwrites any file that already exists and you aren't re-reading the contents of that file before doing the replace.

What you should do is read the text once, do all the replacements and then write the text out once. Something along these lines:

```
Dim sb as new StringBuilder(File.ReadAllText(TextBox2.Text))
Dim allLines = File.ReadAllLines(TextBox1.Text)
For c as Integer = 1 to 24
    sb.Replace("##"&c, allLines(c-1))
Next x

File.WriteAllText(TextBox3.Text, sb.ToString())
```

Note that you really need some error handling in there as well (to make sure there is data in those text boxes--which could also use better names)

You also don't need the call to `File.Create()`. `File.WriteAllText` will [create the file if it does not exist](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143375(v=vs.110).aspx) .